# How to solve this situation about ffmpeg with Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk, ffmpeg, cygwin

I used Android NDK to Compile ffmpeg ，when I run config.sh,so many erros happened,how to solve it.

```
Terry-L@Terry-L-HP /cygdrive/e/Android/android-ndk-r8d/samples/FFmpeg/jni/ffmpeg
$ ./config.sh

Unknown option "".
See ./configure --help for available options.
./config.sh: line 6: --target-os=linux: command not found
./config.sh: line 7: --arch=arm: command not found
./config.sh: line 8: --enable-version3: command not found
./config.sh: line 9: --enable-gpl: command not found
./config.sh: line 10: --enable-nonfree: command not found
./config.sh: line 11: --disable-stripping: command not found
./config.sh: line 12: --disable-ffmpeg: command not found
./config.sh: line 13: --disable-ffplay: command not found
./config.sh: line 14: --disable-ffserver: command not found
./config.sh: line 15: --disable-ffprobe: command not found
./config.sh: line 16: --disable-encoders: command not found
./config.sh: line 17: --disable-muxers: command not found
./config.sh: line 18: --disable-devices: command not found
./config.sh: line 19: --disable-protocols: command not found
./config.sh: line 20: --enable-protocol=file: command not found
./config.sh: line 21: --enable-avfilter: command not found
./config.sh: line 22: --disable-network: command not found
./config.sh: line 23: --disable-mpegaudio-hp: command not found
./config.sh: line 24: --disable-avdevice: command not found
./config.sh: line 25: --enable-cross-compile: command not found
./config.sh: line 26: --cc=/cygdrive/e/Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-li                                                                                                                nux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file                                                                                                                 or directory
./config.sh: line 27: --cross-prefix=/cygdrive/e/Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolcha                                                                                                                ins/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-: No su                                                                                                                ch file or directory
./config.sh: line 28: --nm=/cygdrive/e/Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-li                                                                                                                nux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm: No such file                                                                                                                 or directory
./config.sh: line 29: --extra-cflags=-fPIC -DANDROID: command not found
./config.sh: line 30: --disable-asm: command not found
./config.sh: line 31: --enable-neon: command not found
./config.sh: line 32: --enable-armv5te: command not found
./config.sh: line 33: --extra-ldflags=-Wl,-T,/cygdrive/e/Android/android-ndk-r8d
```

/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/arm-linux-androideabi/lib                                                                                                                /ldscripts/armelf_linux_eabi.x -Wl,-rpath-link=/cygdrive/e/Android/android-ndk-r                                                                                                                8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib -L/cygdrive/e/Android/android-ndk-r8d/p                                                                                                                latforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib -nostdlib /cygdrive/e/Android/android-ndk-r                                                                                                                8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/lib/gcc/arm-linux-andro                                                                                                                ideabi/4.6/crtbegin.o /cygdrive/e/Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-a                                                                                                                ndroideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/crtend.o -lc -                                                                                                                lm -ldl: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using cywin to build ffmpeg, so you will get many problems with it. I recommend you should build it on linux.

The above error maybe missing configure ENV. You need to add $NDK to $PATH.